# Add variables names to json data dynamically

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

I just want to know is there a way by which variable names can by set dynamically . For example this is sample json data

```
let obj={
    "data_type": "data according to date",
    "status_message": "",
    "data": []
}
```

I want to add new variable array in obj.data according to date automatically.
I'll be getting new data everyday so instead of appending in single node , i want it to be in different node according to date.

new format of json

[image: new format of json]

Sorry if this is a noob question, but i couldn't find answer anywhere.

Comment: Do take note of the difference between `[]` and `{}` since your code and your picture of code (**Don't show us pictures of code!!**) differ there.

Comment: `var date = '2018:5:2'; obj.data[date] = [...]`.

Comment: I forgot to set it equals to obj in picture.